# Do you have to pass the application id / secret with every facebook request?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication

I'm working with a facebook client library which only asks for an access token, and not for the application id / secret, in order to make requests.

This is a little strange to me because the Facebook javascript SDK requires the app id as well, and the PHP SDK requires both the app id and the app secret.

Are the app id/secret not necessary, and if I simply supply the access token, that will be enough?

E.g if the user has given my app the publish_stream permission, and I tried to post something to his timeline using only the access token, will that succeed?

(The client I'm using is RestFB for java).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you need to pass the `app-id` and the `app-secret` only when you're exchanging the code  for `access_token` for the first time when the user authenticates your app and you can store this access token in your DB to make further API calls, otherwise it should only be the `access_token` that you need to pass in the API call that you make. And since you are only trying to post something to the users wall, that should only require the users `access_token`.

> There are a few exceptions that explicitly require you to pass the
>   app-id and app-secret like, when you're handling expired tokens.

Comment: When your app is hosted on facebook as an Iframe, then is the oauth_token included in the signature_request that's posted via HTTP POST? Or do you still have to exchange them the first time?

Comment: Nope the oauth_token is by default included in the signature_request posted.